# How to know when Asynchronous post request has completed WP8

Tags: c#, http, post, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I am using following code to send data to server from windows phone 8.

The responseString is coming to be of default value.

However if  check it after few seconds it is updated.

Is there any way to know when the request is completed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Blood_Bank
{
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        String responseString = "amit";
        public event Action Completed;
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new HttpWebRequest object
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mywindowsproject.appspot.com");

            //   request.ContentType = "text/html";

            // Set the Method property to 'POST' to post data to the URI.
            request.Method = "POST";

            // start the asynchronous operation

            postData.Append("name=" + name.Text.ToString()+"&");


            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);


                MessageBox.Show(responseString);         

        }
        private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);


            // Convert the string into a byte array. 
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

            // Write to the request stream.
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }
        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation

            try
            {


                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

                streamResponse.Close();
                streamRead.Close(); response.Close();
                if (Completed != null)
                    Completed();

            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the methods in place that get called when the request is complete. In your method GetResponseCallback, you should have the updated responseString. You could raise an event in that method so that other classes may handle the updates responseString, or handle the logic within the method itself.

See also this [introduction to event based programming in C#](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/introduction-event-driven).